# Is there a limit to wp_remote_get and/or simplexml_load_string from Vimeo?

Tags: php, xml, api

I know *wp_remote_get* is a WordPress function, and that I should be posting this in wordpress.stackexchange, however, I am almost certain my issue lies more on the general PHP side.

**The problem:** I need to retrieve all Vimeo videos found within an album, yet I am only getting 20.

**The approach:**

```
$vmg_feed_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/';
$vmg_user = '2212323';
if($vmg_type == 'user'){ /** just an input variable checking whether the function should search for user or for album. in our case, it searches for album **/
    $vmg_type_url = '';
} else {
    $vmg_type_url = $vmg_type . '/';
}
$vmg_videos_url = $vmg_feed_url . $vmg_type_url . $vmg_user . '/videos.xml';
$videos_result = wp_remote_get($vmg_videos_url);
$vmg_videos = simplexml_load_string($videos_result['body']);
```

The resulting XML is http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/2212323/videos.xml - and as you can see, I am only retrieving 20 videos.

**The question:** Am I missing something? Is there a function/variable that sets a limit to the amount of videos I can retrieve? I know that **wp_remote_get** gives me these attributes ([from the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get)):

**$url**
(string) (required) Universal Resource Locator (URL).
- *Default*: None

**$args**
(array) (optional)
- *Default*: method: GET, timeout: 5, redirection: 5, httpversion: 1.0, blocking: true, headers: array(), body: null, cookies: array()

Any help is truly appreciated. Please let me know if I forgot about any details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor problem is not in wordpress or PHP. It is API limits:

http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple

> Simple API responses include **up to 20** items per page.

You can get more by adding `?page` parameter in next requests.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I missed that. I just found the Simple API page on Vimeo and am now wondering, how I could use the page parameter (with a callback?) to retrieve 60 videos? I know that myurl?page=2 will show me the second page, but how do I implement that into my code above, so that it gets page 1, 2 and 3 and retrieves 60 videos? Thank you!

Comment: You have to make three separate request and combine results. This is very simple operation, so please try doing it on your own first.

Comment: Got it, I thought there might be a simple add-on variable to the request URL. Thanks again!